# Unable to load OMG DDS implementation. Please set org.omg.dds.serviceClassName property.G

Tags: data-distribution-service

I'm a fresh man to OMG DDS and I tried to run the example GreetingPublishingApp. I don't know what should I do.

```
DomainParticipantFactory factory =
    DomainParticipantFactory.getInstance(Bootstrap.createInstance());
DomainParticipant dp = factory.createParticipant();
```

Comment: I think you should provide more information, like which DDS implementation you are using etc?

Also, the code you provide is just creation of a DomainParticipant. What are you trying to accomplish actually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use the new Java5 API, which is still in-progress. The API alone will not help as it is just a facade to an underlying implementation. As far as I know no current implementations support the new API, as it is not yet finished.
Regarding the error message: the intent is to put the class of the concrete implementation into the org.omg.dds.serviceClassName system property.